# My Form Gets submitted on click of any button out of 2

Tags: php, html

no there is no relation between show all and display function.

even i commented the code inside ShowAll function still form gets submitted.

Is there anything related to POST event getting fired when I click on the buttons ?

I also did 1 change today, as I removed the 2nd button code outside the Form Tag Body

OLD code

```
<form name="form2" method="post" action= "submitlogin.php"> 

<td class="label"><br><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit-" size="25" onclick="display()"></td>

<button id='button' onclick="ShowAll()" >Click </button>

</form>
```

New Change

```
<form name="form2" method="post" action= "submitlogin.php"> 

<td class="label"><br><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit-" size="25" onclick="display()"></td>

</form>

<button id='button' onclick="ShowAll()" >Click </button>
```

// Now ShowAll stopped working once its outside the Form Tag Body

Comment: Why you called this display() in submit. post display function definition

Comment: what is inside the JS functions ..

Comment: Well the JS-function ShowAll probably uses some kind of element context and is therefore not working when put in a new context. BTW to stop the form from submitting, just add return false; or something along function ShowAll(event) { event.preventDefault(); doStuff; } this will stop the button from actually do what it usually does.